# Catching undefined javascript variable

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm using Ajax/jsonp to access a remote database.  As such, the response.error is never returned.  I'm trying to catch an instance when the remote server does not return data for whatever reason.  I've tried everything I can think of to catch an undefined condition and I can't seem to catch it.  I've tried to find the variable with Firebug.  I've tried using just about every combination of the following code I can think of and just can't seem to get it to work.

```
                      if ( typeof(data.flightStatuses[0].operationalTimes.publishedDeparture.dateLocal) === "undefined") {
                        alert("flightstats is undefined");
                    }
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated!!!!

I also tried:

```
                      if ( typeof data.flightStatuses === "undefined") {
                        alert("flightstats is undefined");
                    }
```

Above code won't execute alert either....

FINALLY!   This worked...

```
if ( typeof data.flightStatuses[0] === "undefined")
```

I don't really know why, but it did.  thanks your everyone's help!

Comment: What happens if `data`, `flightStatuses`, `operationalTimes` or `publishedDeparture` are also undefined?

Comment: fyi, you don't need typeof unless the leftmost variable may be undefined. in any other case checking for `=== undefined` is pretty safe. Additionally, `typeof` is an operator, not a function so you can omit the `()`

Comment: OK.  GREAT answers.  I'll try a couple of these approaches and report back!  thanks.

Comment: &#^$%   OK.  I tried:                 if ( typeof data.flightStatuses === "undefined") {
          alert("flightstats is undefined");           Still, it won't execute the alert.....
            }

Answer (score 2):

If `data.flightStatuses` is undefined, then `data.flightStatuses[0]` will throw an error. Make you only check if the relevant identifier is undefined:

```
if(typeof data.flightStatuses === "undefined") {
    alert("flightStatuses is undefined");
} else {
    // Here you know data.flightStatuses exists, so you can test data.flightStatuses[0]
    if(typeof data.flightStatuses[0] === 'undefined'){
        alert("flightStatuses[0] is undefined");
    } else {
        // And so on, depending on how much you know about your data source
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work

```
   try {
        dateLocal = typeof (data.flightStatuses[0].operationalTimes.publishedDeparture.dateLocal) !== 'undefined';
        if (dateLocal) {
            // Do something with dateLocal
            // ...
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("flightstats is undefined: " + err);
    }
```

Comment: "? true : false" not needed

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
if (data.flightStatuses[0].operationalTimes.publishedDeparture.dateLocal) === null) {
                        alert("flightstats is undefined");
                    }
```